# How do I access the Ruby AST from C level code?

Tags: c, ruby, tree, interpreter

I understand that the `Ruby 1.8 AST` is traversed at runtime using a big switch statement, and many things like calling a method in a class or parent module involve the interpreter looking up and down the tree as it goes. Is there a straightforward way of accessing this `AST` in a `Ruby C` extension? Does it involve the Ruby extension API, or necessitate hacking the internal data structures directly?

Answer (score 1):

A good starting point is probably to read the source of the [ParseTree](http://rubyforge.org/projects/parsetree/) library, which lets you get at and mess with the AST from ruby.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the tip. You're right - `ParseTree` seems to be the only code out there with any manipulation of the AST going on, except that it's actually written in RubyInline.

So, it's a strange mixture between Ruby and C code. Very interesting reading, though.

The other reference of course is eval.c from Ruby itself.

It's going to take a fair bit of reading of both, to get my head around it.

Comment: hey there! out of interest, what are you writing? :)